# Como obtener el valor de Request URL?

Tags: selenium

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tardes,

Necesitaba crear un código (python o vba) para almacenar en una variable el valor que contenga Request URL (lo marcado en amarillo de la imagen).
¿es posible?

La web que consulto se puede visualizar un pdf, pero no se puede descargar dicho pdf directamente, en cambio en Request URL aparece la url donde esta el pdf descargable.

De igual modo estoy intentando obtener algun valor del html pero no lo obtengo, si alguien me pudiera dar alguna ayuda en esto tambien lo agradezco.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#definimos variable url con la dirección deseada
url = 'https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html'
#buscamos y abrimos
driver.get(url)
#pausar 5 segundo para que cargue
sleep(5)
# get element
#element = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="folletoOnline"]/div[1]')
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'document')
# print element
print(element)
driver.close()
```

respuesta
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="947d1d902fc60b5e0c21d1ce3ee06d1b", element="c2b19567-c297-4ac1-8a04-a5e576a3c31a")>

muchas gracias, seria de gran ayuda obtener solucion a estas dos cuestiones.
un saludo.

Comment: que tipo de dato es la salida?

Comment: Mi idea es meter la url de descarga del pdf en una variable. Por lo cual seria un string.